# How to wrap long super() call to be compliant with PEP-8?

Tags: python, pep8

I have the following code:

```
template_response = super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self).render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

How should I wrap it so it doesn't exceed 78 characters? Currently, the limit occurs right before `*args`.

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: In Python 3, remove the arguments to `super()`: `template_response = super().render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Hit enter after super(.

Comment: Does it matter that much - an 86 char line? Hardly a dilemma... How about just calling your var `tr`? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do:

```
template_response = super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self).render_change_form(
    *args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
template_response = super(
    ExtendedUserAdmin, self
).render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
template_response = super(
    ExtendedUserAdmin, self).render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can store the result of `super()` in a local name:

```
sproxy = super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self)
template_response = sproxy.render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap after the opening parenthesis:

```
class X:
    def render_change_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        template_response = super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self).render_change_form(
            *args, **kwargs)
```

Luckily this is just short enough to fall within the limits.  In general, I break after opening parentheses whenever possible.  If the method name was a little longer, I would introduce a local name for `super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self)` as [@MartijnPieters did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906066/41747).

Answer (score 0):

I often do:

```
template_response = super(ExtendedUserAdmin, self
                          ).render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

As at first look what is in super parenthesis doesn't interest me, that way it's more like in python3

```
template_response = super().render_change_form(*args, **kwargs)
```